# SO local user groups

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, community

Many of SO user would like meet people from SO in the real world (outside matrix).

For this it would be great, if SO have some function for creating user groups (strictly moderated). It's possible?

I know, we don't want build social-community web like facebook, but in real world is good to making connections.

Comment: +1 for "outside matrix"

Comment: would be great to be able to build irl user-groups based on  preferred tags and location (City/Town level) and possibly badges.

Answer (score 9):

I would love to be able to filter users by country on SO. To search for fellow Icelanders.

Comment: I like your idea a whole lot more than I do the author's actual suggestion.

Comment: What point is there in singling them out if you can't communicate with them? :)

Comment: Download the data dump and searching it would be an option...

Comment: Sure, most of us have enough google-fu to find their contact details...

Comment: I asked this as a new question now. Check it here. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/filter-users-by-country

Answer (score 2):

I think it would help if you could find users close to you, if both you and they have added a Location. Although I think this might require multiple fields for the location to ensure that everyone has it entered in a way that can be parsed and geolocated (and that there's enough, since I don't want people who put United States to show up, since they might be on the west coast while I'm on the east coast).

Answer (score 0):

Jeff's [recent post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/stack-overflow-flash-mobs/) about the Birds of a Feather session at this year's OSCON to add a bunch of R content got me thinking along these lines.  It might be nice to have a way of identifying which questions and answers were entered during certain events or by user groups.  This could make organizing the groups easier.

Some of this could be accomplished by tagging but it seems like that would be bad form since the tag wouldn't directly relate to the content of the Q/A, but rather to the poster or event.  I wonder if a group or guild system would be abused.

I also wonder if this is something that would necessarily need to be part of StackOverflow core.  If the platform has a good web service API a group system could be developed by a 3rd party.

Answer (score 0):

As SO is relatively diverse in terms of technologies used, I guess any local "user group" would work better as meeting for a few beers in a pub rather than presentation-type things. If anybody wants a beer/cider in the London/Reading area...

(When I was at university there was a drinking society called "The Society for Putting Things On Top of Other Things". I wonder if they are still going.)