# Filter users by country

Tags: feature-request, user-search, demographics

This was talked about a few podcasts ago. And they referenced some other site that does this.

Currently location is a string but adding a country dropdown (and for the usa a state drop down) could be a great addition to the site.

Then allow for user filtering by country / state.

Comment: Just curious, what specific use cases you have in mind that such filtering would enable?

Comment: *ahem*, these: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/filter-users-by-country/1047#1047

Comment: Why the downvote? This was posted wayyy long ago. Before statoverflow.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Find users in **Iceland**: Google - *site:stackoverflow.com inurl:users "iceland"*
Find users in **Atlanta**: Google - *site:stackoverflow.com inurl:users "Atlanta"*

Of course that only works for those who explicitly stated "Iceland" in their profile :)

Comment: The results page given lists a lot of the users repeatedly due to the multiple views of the user profile page. This isn't a very clean or efficient way of searching for them.

Comment: What alternative do you currently use? :)

Comment: Currently my biggest method of communicating with other users is through the various IRC channels that we inhabit.

Comment: You assumed a step - I'm not questioning the best method of communication (IRC is awesome), I'm asking how to reach them to begin communicating :)

Comment: So far, the only suggestion I've seen for what we'd use these for is narrowing employment searches.  I'm not against that, but not everybody on SO et al. is looking for a job.  Therefore, having it be an opt-in thing like this works nicely.

Answer (score 7):

I like this more than other social networking-esque feature requests like friends and groups. This would allow you to search for those in your area, and then if they have websites and emails to connect with them that way. I am a big proponent of keeping the facebookiness and myspaceiness off StackOverflow as much as possible.

Comment: Wouldn't this be more facebooky?  Facebook lists me as being in a "network" (whatever that is) of my home metropolitan area, and suggests friends based on presumed physical closeness at one time or another.

Comment: David: I don't mind finding people based on criteria, just leave the actual communication off.

Answer (score 6):

Joel also talked about adding a little flag besides the name, and have rankings filtered by country.

I would really like to see this supported directly in the SO-Family

Comment: +1. That would be a great feature

Answer (score 3):

This could prove useful, as you could cross reference with the the "I'm open to employers (not recruiters) contacting me" to give functionality:
Employers can search for candidates near them
Users could restrict that only employers in their country/county/etc. can contact them

Maybe at a future point in time extend this to go down to postal/zip code?

Comment: Postal/zip code is too much, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

And if you want to query the StackExchange database, [check this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/59359/rank-users-by-country).

Comment: +1, Also I would use following WHERE clause since sometines location contains not only contry information, `WHERE (Location LIKE '%' + @country + '%')`

Answer (score 2):

Try using statoverflow sandbox.

http://statoverflow.com/sandbox/

You just have to get the SQL right. For instance [this](http://statoverflow.com/sandbox/?q=select%20*%20from%20users%20where%20location%20like%20%27M%X%%27):

```
select * from users where location like 'M%X%'
```

Would bring most of SO from Mexico ( and some extra from Texas but since it was Mexico once, I guess it's ok )

Comment: I've done that a long time ago, this question is no longer relevant.

Comment: your link doesnt work please delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like [StatOverflow](http://statoverflow.com/sandbox/) approach, as it allows some aditional digging into users.

```
select * from users where location like '%country_here%'
```