# How can I find Stack Overflow users in my region?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Filter users by country.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/filter-users-by-country)

I want to know how many people of my region is registered in Stack Overflow. Is there an option to do this?

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/filter-users-by-country

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using statoverflow sandbox.

http://statoverflow.com/sandbox/

You just have to get the SQL right. I think it would be something like:

```
select * from users where location like 'mine'
```

Comment: Thanks for the link Oscar this is what I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Not yet, Joel talked about adding a little flag next to the user name and adding a feature to search by region.

But there was no more news about that

Comment: I'd like to see that. It works well on http://projecteuler.net.