# Is there a way to retrieve users from a specific state or city?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Hi,

The company I work on would like to be able to find good programmers through SO, but we couldn't find a way to filter users nearby. Is it possible?

Comment: Filling in more of your profile is a good start, but your profile demonstrates that users can't be forced to do so, Samuel ;-D

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/filter-users-by-country

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can go somewhere like the [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) and write an sql query to filter users based on the location field.

Based on what I've seen in the StackQL logs, maybe something like this:

```
SELECT ID AS [User Link], Reputation, Location, AboutMe, WebsiteUrl, LastAccessDate, Age
FROM Users 
WHERE (Location LIKE '%Nebraska%' OR Location LIKE '% NE %' OR Location = 'NE' OR Location LIKE '% NE')
ORDER BY Reputation DESC
```

That'll get you 414 potential candidates.
Direct query link:  https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/104069/stack-overflow-users-in-nebraska

Comment: Assuming they use the location field *and* don't put something in like "Earth"

Comment: @Jared Harley: assuming they *want to be found*

Comment: Please respect people when they **do not select** the "I'm open to employers (not recruiters) contacting me" checkbox

Comment: @Nathan. Agreed.  To bad that tidbit (bit: get it? I kill me) isn't available in the data, but it's still not hard to check the profile on SO first. I even made sure there's a link pointing straight to it.

Answer (score 9):

How about having them *support* the site and place a job listing on [careers.stackoverflow.com](http://careers.stackoverflow.com).