# Find user by location?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Filter users by country](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/filter-users-by-country)

Can I find users by **location**? I wish to know if there are stackoverflow users in my neighborhood.

Answer (score 1):

Unless they list their location on their profile, then no, you can't. And even then there aren't any search flags on the sites that specifically limit the search to user profiles. Perhaps you could try out [some of these queries](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=location) on the Stack Exchange Data Explorer.