# Is it possible to search for users of stack exchange network within certain country

Tags: support, jobs, search

Looking for people to hire, I was wondering if is there any way to search for person of one particular country and *maybe* contact them.

Is there a place for that ?

Thanks, and sorry if this question is out of topic, I wasn't sure after reading the FAQ.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/filter-users-by-country and probably a few others. (In short: no.) As for contacting them: only if they've voluntarily put contact information on their profile.

Comment: Great, that will do it.

Comment: We have a site for that: http://careers.stackoverflow.com