# SO or SE User Groups, is this a good idea?

Tags: feature-request, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add a property of users of 'group'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15945/add-a-property-of-users-of-group)

Not sure if this is too similar to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1026/so-local-user-groups) so apologies if it is

Rather than have some sort of moderated group though, it would be nice to be able to have a view of the activity of a group of users (say other people from my company) rather than only viewing a single user at a time.

A hybrid between a friends and favourites user list or something like twitter follow.

Too similar to the other question, too unrealistic, too departed from your vision for SE/SO. Would love to hear your thoughts?

Thank you for your time

Mac

Comment: This might work for you: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106717/does-so-need-social-networking-features-to-improve-the-experience-for-expert-use

Comment: Woah, I like the idea but it's pretty full blown (or much better thought out :) 
I know these social things can get totally out of hand and degenerate so the last thing you want to do is spoil a winning formula. I guess what I had in mind is a bit more 'monastic' in scope. Just be able to groups users, nothing too extravagant or game-like trying to up your followers count.

Comment: He was trying to find a formula that would work, the answer that talks about doing things based on tags seems like the best approach (and most chance of ever getting implemented).

Comment: yeah it is well thought out (sorry not quick enough with my edits!)